# Bubble is not firing when programmatically Input changed

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

Having an `Input` from `semantic-ui-react` changed when the User writes something, does fire `onChange` and any `parent component` that includes the `Input` fires `onChange` as well. A process called `bubble` .... right?

#### Example

```
<li onChange={this.onListChange}>
  <Input onChange={this.onInputChange}/>
</li>
```

Any change made in the `Input`, fires `onInputChange()` and `onListChange()` together one after another.

Although, when `Input.value/text/content` is changed dynamically, `Input.onChange()` is not called at all. So you have to **call** the `onChange()` function **manually**.

```
setFoo() {
  this.input.value = 'foo';
  this.inputChange();
}
```

But the problem here is, that when we call **inputChange** we don't get as `e.target` the component `Input`, nor `data` has anything to do with it, **and the most important ... :**

**No Bubbling effect.**

Which means that `onListChange()` will not be fired.

### Question:

How can I **achieve** a **proper bugless bubbled** `onChange()` on **Semantic-UI-React**?

Comment: Isn't that what you want to do? Call `inputChange` manually whenever the list is changed?

Comment: Yes, but doing it that way means that you won't have bubble event to the parent components.

I'm really surprised I have to say. 3 Answers till now, 2 of them were deleted because didn't work. This answer will probably be deleted too because it doesn't work too. Did an Issue in Github, no one can answer this question?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're even asking. If you want the parent component to change when a change happens in a child component simply pass an onChange function to the child.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure about `semantic-ui-react` because I've never used it, but this in theory should work (it works for a normal input):

```
setFoo() {
    this.input.value = 'foo';
    const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
    this.input.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work for `Semantic-UI-React` unfortunately. dispatchEvent is not a function of its components.

Comment: @ApostolisAnastasiou Can you post the code rendering the `Input` elem? How are you storing the `this.input` reference to it?

Nevertheless, I'm not quite sure why you want the `onChange` to fire dynamically. If the value is changed programatically, you know that it's changed and can handle the change somewhere else. The input was intentionally build to respond to user interaction